# UIImageView in Apple push notification allertbox

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Can we add an image to the apple push notification alert box?

Comment: No it is not possible. As a minimum, you should read the documentation provided by Apple http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impossible.

Check Local Notifications and Push Notifications guide here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: In short, Notification window is not alike UIAlertView. You can only change title and body and sound.